# Why pip3 installing packages though can't import it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, ubuntu-14.04, python-3.5

i have installed MySQLdb by pip3 but when i'm importing it, it is giving me error. why?

```
pip3 install mysqlclient
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): mysqlclient in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages
```

Now as you see it is already installed but when i'm importing it it shows this:

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Jun 30 2016, 12:36:02) 
[GCC 5.3.1 20160413] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import MySQLdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'MySQLdb'
>>>
```

It is saying no module. I think my ubuntu laptop has two directories of python3 which is causing trouble. One is usr/local/bin and another is in usr/bin. Please help.

Comment: `sudo pip3 install MySQL-python`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two directories for python3 in my ubuntu one is usr/local/bin and one is usr/bin. pip3 is installing the modules for the python usr/bin but when i'm starting python3 in terminal it is starting the usr/local/bin so i changed the default python by

```
alias python=/usr/bin/python3.5
```

and now when i'm starting python3 it is starting the one from usr/bin where modules are installed so now import MySQLdb is working.

Comment: Your problem is that your system uses python2 by default, which is of course uses different package directories with python3. You can start the python3 by calling `python3` instead of `python` (which is alias for python2) in the terminal. But the author has a different problem.

Comment: by calling python3 starts the python3 which is located in usr/local/bin but pip3 installs packages for the python3 in usr/bin so i changed the default python

Comment: are you sure? In my distro python3 located by path /usr/bin/python3 while pip3 packages installed in /usr/local/lib/python3. Perhaps, it's OS-specific issue

Comment: yes but if you install additionally python3 then one more python3 installs in usr/local/bin which does not have any folders to install packages